# How to show custom tooltipComponent headerTooltip below headers in ag-grid react

Tags: typescript, frontend, tooltip, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm creating a custom headerTooltip component in AG grid version 25.3.0, as per the documentation I have registered the custom tooltip component in frameworkComponents and used tooltipComponent in defaultColdefs, I'm getting headerTooltip at the bottom of the table, is the issue related to the version, or I'm missing any step

```
import React from 'react';
import { ITooltipParams } from 'ag-grid-community';

const CustomTooltip = (props: ITooltipParams) => {
  const tooltipStyle: React.CSSProperties = {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    // ...other styles
  };

  return (
    <div style={tooltipStyle}>
      <p>
        <span>Description:</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        your text
      </p>
      <p>
        <span>{props.value}</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CustomTooltip;
```

I was expecting the tooltip to come below header but it's coming below the table